# How do I find the utilities package in the NextJS tailwindcss docs?

Tags: next.js, mdxjs

In the tailwindcss documentation site (https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss.com/tree/master), they have have the following import:

```
import utilities from 'utilities?plugin=width'
```

as part of something like:

```
import utilities from 'utilities?plugin=width'
import { numbersFirst } from '@/utils/sortClasses'
import { ArbitraryValues } from '@/components/ArbitraryValues'
import { BreakpointsAndMediaQueries } from '@/components/BreakpointsAndMediaQueries'
import { HoverFocusAndOtherStates } from '@/components/HoverFocusAndOtherStates'

export const classes = {
  utilities,
  sort: numbersFirst,
}

## Basic usage
... rest of the documentation
```

Looking at package.json, I don't see a package called "utilities". So, I think it must be defined somewhere in the repository, but I can't find it.

Where is this utilities package, and how is it defined?

Comment: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss.com/blob/50cc89f042c4a4bbbeef932c182a65926d22e8ba/next.config.mjs#L79-L90

Comment: You really should add a link to a place where such an import is actually used. E.g. [src/pages/docs/width.mdx](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss.com/blob/master/src/pages/docs/width.mdx#L6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package [tailwindlabs/tailwindcss.com](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss.com) uses webpacks [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) configuration to
map an import named `"utilities"` to the file `tailwindcss/lib/corePlugins.js` *(which is probably created from tailwinds [/src/corePlugins.js](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/src/corePlugins.js#L774))*.

This is done inside the configuration file [next.config.mjs](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss.com/blob/master/next.config.mjs#L79).